# How to view all book reviews in one place?

Tags: reviews, amazon

Is there a way/resource whereby I can see reviews left for all of my books across various outlets without having to check them all individually?

For example, I have three books available on Smashwords, Barnes & Noble and Amazon and rather than going through each retailer and subsequently each book, is there a resource that can pull all of the information in from each outlet for each book and show it to me via a dashboard-type interface?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not aware of any way to do this.

Sorry, it's kind of a lame answer, but I think it's the truth.

Comment: If the answer is "no", then it's "no".